# Completely Lost: Many To Many with Serializers and Update in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, vue.js

I've been looking at this for several hours now and I'm not finding the solution. I'm just not getting it.

I have a parent that has many children. I've created a view that allows me to get all of the parent's children. Now I want to end that list and do  PATCH to the parent with the new list of children. I understand that I need to write a custom `update` method, but I can't figure out how to make this work.

Here's my Child Serializer:

```
class ChildSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = models.Child
        fields = ('id', 'url', 'name',)
```

Here's my Parent Serializer:

```
class ParentSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    children = ChildSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = models.Parent
        fields = ('id', 'url', 'name', 'children',)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        submitted_children = validated_data.get('children')
        if submitted_children:
            for child in submitted_children:
                child_instance = Child.objects.get(id=child.id)
                instance.children.add(child_instance)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

My understanding of what needs to happen is...

1. Get the submitted children `validated_data.pop('children')`
2. Loop through them and add each one to the parent.children many to many
3. Save the parent model

I've probably tried a dozen different ideas here, but I can't seem to get this to work. The code above doesn't change the children_set.

Any suggestions are much welcome.

For reference, i've studied the following:

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writable-nested-representations

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#validation

[django rest framework many to many json write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33179052/django-rest-framework-many-to-many-json-write)

And a bunch more but I can't remember them right now

UPDATE:

[{"id":2,"url":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/children/2","first_name":"Tom","last_name":"Jones","date_of_birth"
:"1969-03-14"}]

Comment: Does `submitted_children` contain the expected values?

Comment: I mean in the update method. Have you printed it?

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but what do you mean by "printed it?"

Comment: print(submitted_children) or any other way of debugging

Comment: Huh. It's empty when I do the patch.

Comment: There you go :) Can you post your json?

Comment: Ok. I can see now that what was being sent was empty. SO there was nothing to patch. However, now that I'm sending over my JSON properly I'm getting: {"non_field_errors":["Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got list."]} . I've added the JSON to the question.

Comment: See my example here for a simple solution to the problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55043187/5626788

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your JSON is not correct. It should look like this:

```
{
 "id": 1,
 "url": "some url",
 "name": "John Smith",
 "children": [
   {"id": 2, "url": "child url", "name": "childs name"},
   {"id": 3, ...}
 ]
}
```

Comment: OHHHH! The way I was sending it the API had no idea where to put it. And for a PATCH it'll JUST write the children. Is that right?

Comment: the way you created the `update` method, it will just write the children.

Answer (score 0):

Go here for a simple solution to the problem. It doesn't involve overriding the update methods so is generic across serializers using M2M:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55043187/5626788

The key is instantiating a serializer, passing the instance, data dictionary and the `partial=True` flag, so that any fields given are updated except the primary key.